# PHP-FPM with NGINX - Error log missing line breaks after update

Tags: php, nginx

I'm working on a update for a old system whose versions are **PHP7.1**, **NGINX 1.10.1** on an old **Ubuntu 14.04.4.**

The apps logs were displayed like this:

```
2022/03/10 07:05:40 [error] 23694#23694: *89040 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: .
PHP message: ..................................................[ Developer Version ]
PHP message: .
PHP message: Started GET / (1.2.3.4:34210)
PHP message: Parameters = []
PHP message: Resource Selected: ControllerName
PHP message: Session started: [123 , (**anon**)]
PHP message: Response = {"class":"HtmlResponse","code":200}" while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.2.3.4, server: oldserver.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "4.3.2.1"
```

However, after upgrading to Ubuntu **20.04.4**, **PHP 8.0.16** and Nginx 1.18.0 all my logs are clumped together without the line breaks, like this:

```
2022/03/10 07:49:17 [error] 44423#44423: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: .PHP message: ..................................................[ Developer Version ]PHP message: .PHP message: Started GET /url-name (1.2.3.4:58262)PHP message: Parameters = []PHP message: Resource Selected: ControllerName message: Session started: [abc123 , (**anon**)]PHP message: Response = {"class":"HtmlResponse","code":200}" while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.2.3.4, server: servername.com, request: "GET /url-name HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock:", host: "servername.com"
```

The logs are created on dispatch.php file like this:

```
$logger->error('.');
$logger->error('..................................................[ Developer Version ]');
$logger->error('.');
```

And the **$logger** class basically calls the error_log method

```
error_log($pf.$msg);
```

Does anyone know to resolve this? Help appreciated, please

Answer (score 0):

Just add new line

```
error_log( $pf . $msg . "\n");
```

Comment: The thing is, if i started this server locally with **php -S** it works as should be. If i added a new \n it will break **two** lines